# NServiceBus distributor cannot create queues on clustered MSMQ

Tags: msmq, nservicebus, windows-server-2008-r2, failover

I'm trying to set up a NServiceBus distributor on a Windows failover cluster. I've successfully followed the "official" guides and most of the things seem to work nicely. Except for actually starting the distributor on the cluster. When it starts it tries to create it's queues on the clustered MSMQ, but is denied permission:

> Unhandled Exception: Magnum.StateMachine.StateMachineException: Exception occurred in Topshelf.Internal.ServiceController`1[[NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows.WindowsHost, NServiceBus.Host, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9fc386479f8a226c]] during state Initial while handling OnStart ---> System.Exception: Exception when starting endpoint, error has been logged. Reason: The queue does not exist or you do not have sufficient permissions to perform the operation. ---> System.Messaging.MessageQueueException: **The queue does not exist or you do not have sufficient permissions to perform the operation.**

I'm able to create queues when opening the clustered MSMQ manager, but even if I run the distributor using my own account it gets this error.

Something that might be related, is that I cannot change properties on the Message Queuing object in the clustered MSMQ manager. For instance, I try to change the message storage limit, I get this error:

> The properties of TEST-CLU-MSMQ cannot be set
>
> Error: This operation is not supported for Message Queuing installed in workgroup mode

I can however change this setting on the node's MSMQ settings, and those are also installed in workgroup mode.

Any ideas? I've tried reinstalling the cluster and services and just about everything, to no avail. Environment is Windows Server 2008R2

Comment: Did you tick the "use network name for computer name" after you added the distributor as a clustered resource?

Comment: Can you link to the guides you are using so we can get the gist of the steps you are taking?

Comment: Turns out something was iffy with the cluster setup. We were using a cluster which has been used to test out new stuff, and probably some old cruft was interfering. We stopped being able to fail over even the queueing service, so then we just threw out the install and redid from start. Worked immediatly.

Comment: @AdamFyles: For the record: http://nservicebus.com/DistributorV3.aspx and http://www.make-awesome.com/2010/10/deploying-nservicebus-in-a-windows-failover-cluster/

Comment: Glad you got it to work!

Comment: Btw, the reason you could not change the storage limit for the clustered MSMQ instance is because MSMQ was installed in workgroup mode. Only MSMQ with Active Directory integration can change the limit through that interface. For workgroup mode you need to edit a registry entry and restart the clustered MSMQ instance. Check out http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2009/10/20/setting-storage-quotas-for-multiple-instances-of-msmq-on-a-cluster.aspx for the correct instructions.

Comment: @janovesk: Very interesting! Although, non-clustered instances of MSMQ in workgroup mode seem to be able to set the limit in the interface? I also tried switching mode in our test environment (after reinstall), and that did not seem to make the error go away... Any ideas?